# Why doesn't it work when using Python to encrypt, then Ruby to decrypt?

Tags: python, ruby, encryption

I'm trying to `encrypt` then `base64_encode` a string using Python, and `base64_decode` then `decrypt` the result with Ruby, but the string is messed up.

I don't see any difference in the two methods. I tried using the 128-bit AES-CFB algorithm, but had no success.

Here's my Python code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.randpool import RandomPool
from base64 import standard_b64encode, standard_b64decode

key = "abcdefghijklmnop"
en = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, "0000000000000000")
cipher = en.encrypt("apple")
cipher64 = standard_b64encode(cipher)
```

`cipher64` contains: `WqF9Zj0=`

My Ruby code is:

```
require "openssl"
require 'digest/sha2'
require 'base64'


de = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-128-cfb")
de.decrypt
de.key = "abcdefghijklmnop"
de.iv = "0000000000000000"
plain = de.update("WqF9Zj0=".unpack('m')[0])
de.final
puts plain
```

`plain` contains a different string than `"apple"`. I get the same result if my string's length is 16, to avoid a padding problem.

I guess it's a parameter problem, but I can't figure out what. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

PyCrypto uses a different `segment_size`

When encoding, specify `segment_size`, and pad the plain text.

```
from base64 import standard_b64encode

from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def pad(x, n=16):
    p = n - (len(x) % n)
    return x + chr(p) * p

key = "abcdefghijklmnop"
en = AES.new(key=key, mode=AES.MODE_CFB, IV="0" * 16, segment_size=128)
cipher = en.encrypt(pad("apple"))
cipher64 = standard_b64encode(cipher)
print cipher64
```

Using the above code, you will get `apple\x03\x03\x03`. On the Ruby side, you should remove the padding.

Ruby part (decoding):

```
require "openssl"

de = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-128-cfb")
de.decrypt
de.key = "abcdefghijklmnop"
de.iv = "0000000000000000"
plain = de.update(ARGV[0].unpack('m')[0]) + de.final
plain = plain[0...-plain[-1].ord]
puts plain
```

Alternatively, you can use M2Crypto, which has no need to remove the padding on the Ruby side:

```
from base64 import standard_b64encode

import M2Crypto.EVP

key = "abcdefghijklmnop"
iv = "0000000000000000"
en = M2Crypto.EVP.Cipher('aes_128_cfb', key, iv, 1)
cipher = en.update('apple') + en.final()
cipher64 = standard_b64encode(cipher)
print cipher64
```

Comment: Thanks, but i still have problem if the input apple string is longer than 8 characters. On python side i' ve: `from Crypto.Cipher import AES    en = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, "0000000000000000", segment_size = 64)   cipher = en.encrypt(pad(sys.argv[1]))` and on ruby side i' ve: `require "openssl"    decryptobj = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("AES-256-CFB")` . Unfortunately M2Crypto is not reachable in my case.

Comment: Ah, found the solution finally: i need to use segment_size = 128 by encoding and 16 byte long padding as well :- ).

Comment: @user2194805, I fixed that. I also added ruby code that strip padding.

Comment: Note for future users - this answer almost tripped me up. The segment size is ONLY an issue in CFB mode.